# How to avoid infinite recursion in self-referencing many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models

In order to implement a delegation system in my Django application, I have a self-referencing many-to-many relation on my person model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class Person(AbstractUser):
    delegates = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

I believe there are two pitfalls (ways to trigger infinite recursions) to this approach:

1. If User A set himself as delegate (probably dumb but feasible)
2. If User A set User B as delegate and User B set User A as delegate

What would be the right approach to avoid such cases?

Comment: There are actually an infinite amount of pitfalls, for example `A` can set `B` as delegate who sets `C` as delegate who sets `A` as delegate, etc. for an arbitrary number, you can make a "cycle" with that number of people.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True...

Comment: maybe https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt ? see https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/8ef52b348c285b660b2b08e0a1c707b01e2c9f76/tests/myapp/doctests.txt#L300

Comment: @PawełKordowski Thanks for the tip. This library looks really interesting. It can't apply here because the delegation is not a 'tree' per se. I may be the delegate of multiple persons and I may delegate to several persons. It is really a many-to-many relation and not a one-to-many.